# how do I add attributes to the html tag in haml?

Tags: haml, formtastic

For me to use formtastic, it looks like I need this as my html tag:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

How do I do thsi in HAML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you add [attributes to any other tag](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attributes) in Haml:

```
%html{:xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "xml:lang" => "en", :lang => "en"}
```

Haml actually has a [built in helper method for these attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#html_attrs-instance_method), so you can just do:

```
%html{html_attrs}
```

which defaults to 'en-US' as the language, or pass the language string you want to use:

```
%html{html_attrs('en')}
```